# Why is auth plugin called with PreparedRequest instead of Request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to write a custom Authentication plugin for the python requests library.  The plugin needs to inspect and modify the query string (for GET) or multi-part form data (for POST).  This would have been easy to do had the plugin been called with the transparent `Request` object.  But it is called with a `PreparedRequest` instead, which is opaque.  This IMO makes the whole auth plugin mechanism rather unwieldy.

Have a look at [httpie-hmac-auth](https://github.com/guardian/httpie-hmac-auth/blob/master/httpie_hmac_auth.py#L22), for example, which uses `urlparse` to extract the data it needs.  Had it received a `Request` object, this would not have been necessary.  Working with a multipart/form-data body involves more footwork/code duplication.

Is there a compelling reason for this design that I'm missing?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, Having examined the code, I'm pretty confident the only reasonable alternative is to wrap the call to `requests.get`, etc. Not terribly satisfying, but acceptable in my case.  I rephrased the question slightly; is it any less off-topic in your opinion?